# Procedure Insert value from other table

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

**I am getting error in below simple procedure**

```
Create or Replace PROCEDURE "My Procedure" 
  (
    vendor_name in VARCHAR2
  )
BEGIN
INSERT INTO cust_vendors_test (cust_vendor_name) 
select  pv.vendor_name from po_vendors@prod09 pv
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two missing things `IS` in header of procedure, and `semicolon` after sql.
Below code works:

```
Create or Replace PROCEDURE "My Procedure" 
  (
    vendor_name in VARCHAR2
  ) IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO cust_vendors_test (cust_vendor_name) 
select  pv.vendor_name from po_vendors@prod09 pv;
END;
/
```

But you'd better naming this procedure like `My_Procedure` instead of `"My Procedure"` to alleviate calling.

Answer (score 2):

Put a semicolon at the end of your `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO cust_vendors_test (cust_vendor_name) 
  select  pv.vendor_name from po_vendors@prod09 pv;
                                                  ^
```

A couple additional suggestions:

- Next time, post the error message. You probably would have had an answer immediately if you'd done so.
- Reconsider the procedure name. You'll go through a lot of unnecessary grief calling a proc that (a) has a space in its name and (b) has a case-sensitive name.

Answer (score 0):

Zunain, what is the specific error that you are getting?

Without knowing exactly what we are dealing with I have reformatted and here are my suggestions.

```
USE [MyDatabase]
GO

DROP PROCEDURE [Schema].[MyProcedure]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [Schema].[MyProcedure]
    @vendor_name  VARCHAR(100)

AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO cust_vendors_test 
    (
        cust_vendor_name
    ) 
SELECT  pv.vendor_name AS cust_vendor_name
FROM    po_vendors@prod09 AS pv

END
```

Comment: The question is Oracle, not SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use 'exists' before then create the procedure
i.e...

```
IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE NAME = "My Procedure") BEGIN DROP PROCEDURE "My Procedure" END;

Create PROCEDURE "My Procedure" 
AS
INSERT INTO cust_vendors_test (cust_vendor_name) VALUES
(select  pv.vendor_name from po_vendors@prod09 pv)
GO;
```